# Postgres aggregate nested jsonb array values

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

In Postgres 11.x I am trying to aggregate elements in a nested jsonb object which has an array field into a single row per device_id. Here's example data for a table called `configurations`.

| id | device_id | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | "{""sensors"": [{""other_data"": {}, ""sensor_type"": 1}], ""other_data"": {}}" |
| 2 | 1 | "{""sensors"": [{""other_data"": {}, ""sensor_type"": 1}, {""other_data"": {}, ""sensor_type"": 2}], ""other_data"": {}}" |
| 3 | 1 | "{""sensors"": [{""other_data"": {}, ""sensor_type"": 3}], ""other_data"": {}}" |
| 4 | 2 | "{""sensors"": [{""other_data"": {}, ""sensor_type"": 4}], ""other_data"": {}}" |
| 5 | 2 | "{""sensors"": null, ""other_data"": {}}" |
| 6 | 3 | "{""sensors"": [], ""other_data"": {}}" |

My goal output would have a single row per device_id with an array of distinct sensor_types, example:

| device_id | sensor_types |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1,2,3] |
| 2 | [4] |
| 3 | [ ] *null would also be fine here* |

Tried a bunch of things but running into various problems, here's some SQL to set up a test environment:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE configurations(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   device_id SERIAL,
   data JSONB
);

INSERT INTO configurations(device_id, data) VALUES
    (1, '{ "other_data": {}, "sensors": [ { "sensor_type": 1, "other_data": {} } ] }'),
    (1, '{ "other_data": {}, "sensors": [ { "sensor_type": 1, "other_data": {} }, { "sensor_type": 2, "other_data": {} }] }'),
    (1, '{ "other_data": {}, "sensors": [ { "sensor_type": 3, "other_data": {} }] }'),
    (2, '{ "other_data": {}, "sensors": [ { "sensor_type": 4, "other_data": {} }] }'),
    (2, '{ "other_data": {}, "sensors": null }'),
    (3, '{ "other_data": {}, "sensors": [] }');
```

Quick note, my real table has about 100,000 rows and the jsonb data is much more complicated but follows this general structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSONB `null` causes some problems in Postgres and should rather be avoided when possible. You can convert the value to an empty array with the expression

```sql
coalesce(nullif(data->'sensors', 'null'), '[]')
```

The first attempt:

```sql
select device_id, array_agg(distinct value->'sensor_type') as sensor_types
from configurations
left join jsonb_array_elements(coalesce(nullif(data->'sensors', 'null'), '[]')) on true
group by device_id;

 device_id | sensor_types
-----------+--------------
         1 | {1,2,3}
         2 | {4,NULL}
         3 | {NULL}
(3 rows)
```

may be unsatisfactory because of `nulls` in the result. When trying to remove them

```sql
select device_id, array_agg(distinct value->'sensor_type') as sensor_types
from configurations
left join jsonb_array_elements(coalesce(nullif(data->'sensors', 'null'), '[]')) on true
where value is not null
group by device_id;

 device_id | sensor_types
-----------+--------------
         1 | {1,2,3}
         2 | {4}
(2 rows)
```

`device_id = 3` disappears. Well, we can get all `device_ids` from the table:

```sql
select distinct device_id, sensor_types
from configurations
left join (
    select device_id, array_agg(distinct value->'sensor_type') as sensor_types
    from configurations
    left join jsonb_array_elements(coalesce(nullif(data->'sensors', 'null'), '[]')) on true
    where value is not null
    group by device_id
    ) s
using(device_id);

 device_id | sensor_types
-----------+--------------
         1 | {1,2,3}
         2 | {4}
         3 |
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! A few little tricks in there I wasn't aware of. Out of curiosity if I was looking to make this perform well are there any easy index wins or would it make sense to look at a materialized view?

Comment: The `jsonb_array_elements()` function is indeed expensive, unfortunately there is no index to speed it up.